# C# string masking/formatting/filtering with or without regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-formatting

Hopefully this isn't too complicated, I just can't seem to find the answer I need.

I have a string with variables in, such as: `this is a %variable% string`
The format of the variables within the string is arbitrary, although in this example we're using the filter `%{0}%`

I am wanting to match variable names to properties and ideally I don't want to loop through `GetProperties`, formatting and testing each name. What I'd like to do is obtain "variable" as a string and test that.

I already use RegEx to get a list of the variables in a string, using the given filter:

`string regExSyntax = string.Format(syntax, @"(?<word>\w+)");`
but this returns them WITH the '%' (e.g. '%variable%') and as I said, that filter is arbitrary so I can't just do a string.Replace.

This feels like it should be straight-forward....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your regex syntax is: `string regExSyntax = string.Format(syntax, @"(?<word>\w+)");`, I assume you're then going to create a `Regex` and use it to match against some string:

```
Regex reExtractVars = new Regex(regExSyntax);
Match m = reExtractVars.Match(inputString);
while (m.Success)
{
    // get the matched variable
    string wholeVar = m.Value;  // returns "%variable%"

    // get just the "word"
    string wordOnly = m.Groups["word"].Value;  // returns "variable"

    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Or have I completely misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Bloody hell, I knew it'd be easy. This is definitely the answer I need, although Guidhouse's answer was also totally valid. I didn't know you could access groups like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
   "(?<word>\w+)"
```

Is just capturing anything alphnumeric and putting it into a named capturing group called "Word"

You might be interested in learning about lookbehind and lookahead. For example:

```
"(?<=%)(?<word>\w+)(?=%)"
```

You can make it a bit more generic with putting your filter in a seperate variable:

```
    string Boundie = "%";
    string Expression = @"(?<=" + Boundie + @")(?<word>\w+)(?=" + Boundie + @")";
```

I hope this is anywhere near what you are looking for.

Comment: That's where I was going... ;-)

Comment: Perfect :) This shows my inexperience with RegEx, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: In case you have another Boundie that is a special Regex-character (for example $) you have to escape it before you construct the Expression:  string Boundie = Regex.Escape("$");

Answer (score 0):

Acron,

If you're going to roll-your own script parser... apart from being "a bit mad", unless that's the point of the exercise (is it?), then I strongly suggest that you KISS it... Keep It Simple Stoopid.

So what denotes a VARIABLE in your scripting syntax? Is it the percent signs? And they're fixed, yes? So `%name%` is a variable, but #comment# is NOT a variable... correct? The phrase "that filter is arbitrary" has me worried. What's a "filter"?

If this isn't homework then just use an existing scripting engine, with existing, well defined, well known syntax. Something like [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/), for example.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: It's not homework no, but the usage is so, so primitive, there really is no point in going down the route of a fully-blown parser. But you're quite right, I could enforce a syntax, I just like to keep it as open-ended as possible. Knowing my industry, I'm likely to get feedback along the lines of "% are too ugly. Can we use smiley faces instead? :)variable(:"

Comment: So you tell the hairdressers "Doctor Chopper proscribes a large cup of... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unkIVvjZc9Y